# SEO Impact: Rewriting image urls in htaccess

Tags: seo, htaccess, images, url-rewriting

I'm currently looking to leverage Cloudflare Image Resizing on a sizeable Wordpress multisite network.  Changing all the image requests across the site to reflect the Cloudflare URL is of course going to be a massive undertaking so I'm considering rewriting any incoming requests for an image to the new URL format.  Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|png|webp|gif)$
RewriteRule ^/?wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://www.ldc.com/cdn-cgi/image/quality=75/wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is there a negative SEO impact in considering this approach?  I'm guessing having a 301 for every image on the site isn't ideal.